# Python: how to have code apply to all failures

Tags: python, debugging, pdb, try-except

I'm working with the pdb module in python; I just recently found out about it, so I'm a beginner.  What I want to do is have a variable that, if True, will call set_trace() on ALL failures that occur in the script without putting it all in a try/except statement.  For example, I want the following functionality without the try/except:

```
from pdb import set_trace

debug = True
try:
    #entire script here

except Exception, e:
    if debug:
        set_trace()
    else:
        print e
```

Is there a way to do this without that huge try except statement (also without having to do an if-statement for every single command that could have a failure)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make a custom [`excepthook`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook).

> When an exception is raised and uncaught, the interpreter calls sys.excepthook
>     with three arguments, the exception class, exception instance, and a traceback
>     object

---

```
import sys
import pdb

debug = True

def excepthook(type_, value, traceback):
    if debug:
        pdb.set_trace()
    else:
        print(value)
        # Per mgilson's suggestion, to see the full traceback error message
        # sys.__excepthook__(type_, value, traceback)   

sys.excepthook = excepthook

1 / 0
```

---

If you want the usual traceback error message when `debug` is `False`, then the above could be simplified to

```
if debug:
    sys.excepthook = lambda type_, value, traceback: pdb.set_trace()
```

Comment: hmm never seen that before.  Do you have to pass any values into the excepthook method?  Or is that done automatically?

Comment: You might also want to call `sys.__excepthook__(type, value, traceback)` from your handler if you want to see the traceback printed on the screen ...

Comment: @user2869231: Per the docs, "When an exception is raised and uncaught, the interpreter calls sys.excepthook with three arguments, the exception class, exception instance, and a traceback object."